# Can't parse Json using RcppSimdJson in R

Tags: r, json

I have a weird issue. Was trying to parse a json that comes from a dataframe I exported in Python. Everything worked until I stumbled into a dataframe that has a problem in one of its 300+ columns. After some iterations I found the column that generates problems. In short, this:

```
a = '[{"d1_opcionb":"","d1_monto":""},
{"d1_opcionb":1.0,"d1_monto":281648.34213488},
{"d1_opcionb":1.0,"d1_monto":241412.86468704}]'
a %>% RcppSimdJson::fparse()
```

Brings the following error:

```
Error in .deserialize_json(json = json, query = query, empty_array = empty_array,  : 
  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 14) > this->size() (which is 13)
```

But something like this doesn't:

```
a = '[{"d1_opcion":"","d1_opcionb":""},
{"d1_opcion":1.0,"d1_opcionb":1.0},
{"d1_opcion":1.0,"d1_opcionb":1.0}]'
a %>% RcppSimdJson::fparse()
```

I'm not seeing any major differences. I need to use RcppSimdJson because efficiency is key in my project. Is there something wrong with the first json? any fixes? Thanks!

Edit: while writing I noticed that the only thing that stood out was that d1_monto has is a big float with lots of decimals. After removing three of them the code runs. Any ideas why the package fails with more than 5 decimals?

Comment: That is possibly an error message from the underlying `simdjson` library itself.

Comment: It's probably not only the decimals but a total of 14 digits. Up to 16 digits it should work, though. So I really can't say any more.

Comment: Just had the same thought as @RuiBarradas and wrapped your "overly precise" floating point values in to `"` to parse as string.  That also works.   In short:  it is your data model.

Comment: Tried with one digit and six decimals and the problem still arose (arised?)

Comment: @RuiBarradas it doesn't seem to be due to 14 digits specifically. `RcppSimdJson::fparse('[{"var":""}, {"var":0.12345}]')` works but `RcppSimdJson::fparse('[{"var":""}, {"var":0.123456}]')` doesn't